# The USA's spending on or in this category

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

As far as I know, we normally say "**in a category**" and "**spending on something**". Which of the following sentences is grammatical?

1. *The USA's spending **on** this category was significant.*
2. *The USA's spending **in** this category was significant.*

Answer (score 2):

The two phrases [spending on and spending in](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spending+on%2Cspending+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) are used for different purposes.  For [*services* like *health* or *infrastructure*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spending%20on%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), or similar, we say ***spending on***.
For [countries or years](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spending%20in%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), we say ***spending in***.

This second chart further demonstrates that we use *on* for [services](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spending+on+*_NOUN%2Cspending+in+*_NOUN&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

However, if we include the words ['this category'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spending+on+this+category%2Cspending+in+this+category&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), *in* is more common.

> The USA's spending *in* this category was significant.

The other example is also acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

For statistics and numbers (in economics/business):
U.S. **spending on** something, which as seen below are three different categories of spending.

- Total nominal *spending on medicines* in the U.S. from 2002 to 2022 (in billion U.S. dollars)

[US total expenditure on medicine_from Statista's statistics](https://www.statista.com/statistics/238689/us-total-expenditure-on-medicine/)

- U.S. *spending on debt interest* climbs
  $659B outlay this year nearly double that of ’21,Treasury Department reports

October 22, 2023 at 3:00 a.m.

[Arkansas online](https://www.arkansasonline.com/news/2023/oct/22/us-spending-on-debt-interest-climbs/)

- U.S. *consumer spending on media and entertainment* will increase 4.8 percent a year through 2017, with digital consumption finally rivaling physical sales, according to a report yesterday.

[Bloomberg News](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2013-06-04/mobile-tv-to-dominate-growth-in-consumer-entertainment-spending)

VERSUS:

**spending in** a place:

- Using survey data, Leo shows that US spending in Africa is badly misaligned with Africans’ own priorities.
  [Center for Global Development](https://www.cgdev.org/blog/one-way-not-leave-global-fund-money-table)

[Please note: in the press, etc. we use U.S. in American English, not USA in contexts such as these regarding government spending aka expenditure.

Answer (score 0):

We normally spend money **on** *something*.

> The company spent a lot of money in Q1 on transportation.

But once you begin to abstract the real world situation into charts and graphs and spreadsheets with labels, and then start speaking of the document, the document becomes a thing in its own right, while remaining at the same time a pointer to the real world that underlies it, and you would use different prepositions depending on whether you were referring to the abstraction or to the wordly things that underly the abstraction.

For example:

```
TRANSPORTATION.......ENTERTAINMENT......R&D
$50M.................$100M..............$3M
```

> The company spent far more *on* entertainment than it did *on* R&D. Spending *in* the former category was primarily *on* lavish parties at gambling casinos. Included in the entertainment number are over $50M in gambling losses.

**category** is an abstract "bucket".